# Why am I getting a compilation error on this one?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The following program produces some syntax error on line 15th. I do not understand the reason for the error.

```
declare
 value_1 INTEGER(5);
 value_2 INTEGER(5);
 value_3 INTEGER(5);
 value_4 INTEGER(5);
begin
 value_1 := 20;
 value_2 := 40;
 value_3 := 60;
 value_4 := 80;
 if value_1 > value_2
 then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_1 > Value_2');
 end if;
 elsif value_4 > value_3 # statement 15
 then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_4 > Value_3');
 end if;
 end;
```

The error that gets thrown :

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUE_4" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
Error starting at line 1 in command:
declare
 value_1 INTEGER(5);
 value_2 INTEGER(5);
 value_3 INTEGER(5);
 value_4 INTEGER(5);
begin
 value_1 := 20;
 value_2 := 40;
 value_3 := 60;
 value_4 := 80;
if value_1 > value_2
then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_1 > Value_2');
end if;
elsif value_4>value_3
then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_4 > Value_3');
end if;
end;

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUE_4" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What error is it ? How do I get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  only issue with your statement I can see is the extra `end if;`

**SQL Statement**

```
declare
 value_1 INTEGER(5);
 value_2 INTEGER(5);
 value_3 INTEGER(5);
 value_4 INTEGER(5);
begin
 value_1 := 20;
 value_2 := 40;
 value_3 := 60;
 value_4 := 80;
 if (value_1 > value_2) then 
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_1 > Value_2');
 elsif (value_4 > value_3) then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_4 > Value_3'); 
 end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working man...'m i right?

```
declare
 value_1 INTEGER(5);
 value_2 INTEGER(5);
 value_3 INTEGER(5);
 value_4 INTEGER(5);
begin
 value_1 := 20;
 value_2 := 40;
 value_3 := 60;
 value_4 := 80;
 if (value_1 > value_2)
 then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_1 > Value_2');

 elsif (value_4 > value_3)
 then
  dbms_output.put_line('Value_4 > Value_3');
 end if;
 end;
 /
```

you have closed the if statement and again open elsif statement..i think this is the mistake.